# BIRT report asking for parameters when trying to print in Maximo

Tags: eclipse, printing, birt, maximo, report-designer

When I create a BIRT report that uses the list parameter I have to trashcan the parameters in Maximo so that the BIRT parameter dialog box will pop up with my list parameter because Maximo does not like list parameters.

Now I have an issue with printing the report. Whenever a user tries to print a report that uses the BIRT parameter dialog box, the parameters appear when the report is first ran and again when they try to print. I do not want the parameters to appear again when the user tries to print.

I've already tried __format='pdf' but found out that this does not work in my version of Maximo.

Comment: What version of BIRT are you using, what version of Maximo? What do you mean with 'list' parameter? Is it the where clause as used by the list page on most Maximo applications?